# Music Store Example

Tags: java, store

I just need a step in the right direction. I am working on some homework for a basic java class and I can't seem to recall what I should do here. I do not want to use an array though, I do know that. Here is the code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Store
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
{ Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("How many songs would you like to purchase?");
    int numSongs = s.nextInt();


for(int i = 0; i < numSongs; i++) {
  System.out.println("Enter the length of the songs: ");
  int lengthSongsi = s.nextInt();
                                  }
}    
}
```

I need to be able to store user-defined variables. The amount is unknown until the user tells us. I am not sure how to go about doing this without overwriting the last variable. If an array is the only way, I will use it

Comment: What is your reasoning for not using an Array? That would be helpful with storing multiple variables defined at runtime.

Comment: Because I am not comfortable with them yet, however this would be good practice.

Comment: Yes :) Here is a hint to start you off: you could use the first Scanner input to initialize the array -- `String[] songArray = new String[numSongs];`

This will give you a `songArray` whose size is equal to the number of songs being purchased.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use an `ArrayList`. This is like an array, but it's dynamic, so you don't need to define the length initially:

```
ArrayList mList = new ArrayList();
```

You can also define types, like so:

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then, when you want to add data, you do:

```
mlist.add("My Value");
```

For more info, check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: It's a basic data structure of Java. It's neither more or less complicated. And it's the right tool for this type of situation.

Comment: Just because he neglected to mention an ArrayList doesn't mean that they can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As people suggested, use an ArrayList or an Array. Easy way to do would just be constantly add them to your ArrayList while some parameter remains true.

Also, and this is just my style of code, I always have the first { start after the declaration so instead of say if{.... it would be:

```
if
{..... makes code easier.
```

As for the code aspect of it, you could try this:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> mList = new ArrayList();
 for(int i = 0; i < numSongs; i ++)
 {
     System.out.println("Enter Song Length");
     int lengthSongsi = s.nextInt();
     mList.add(lengthSongsi);

    //if you want to access the length of the song at a particular point
    //just access it as you would any normal array, so it could look like
    //System.out.println("Song length at index " + i + "is: " + mList.get(i));
  }
```

If it doesn't work let me know. I haven't run it through an IDE yet as I am currently at work.

Comment: And if you want to be able to access it from outside of its scope (aka outside of the {} bracers) you can declare the variables you want on a "global" level. That is, declare the variable(s) right after your class declaration. So like: public cass xxxx{ variable here